# How to prevent keep-alive in a HTTP 1.1 request?

Tags: http, http-headers, keep-alive, http-1.1

I'm implementing a simple HTTP client.

Which header should I add to a HTTP 1.1 request so it won't keep alive?

Comment: Have You tried `Connection: close` as mentioned in [RFC2068-14.10](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2068#section-14.10) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add header: `Connection: close`. Currently all connections are permanent and client must explicitly claim that it wants to close the connection.